# Count total games played in a league standings template

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in Google sheets

I've created a league standings template here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aTJsKkORRka1f4Z3Ibb87XGq-6Sv3qFaCYSsW8D3kHM/edit?usp=sharing

The last thing I'm really hung up on is calculating the amount of games that each team has played. Basically I need the G column to use the formula for each cell to see if the corresponding team has completed their games from the 'League Scores' table.

I currently have this formula:

```
=countif(filter($C4:$C, $B4:$B=$J$4), "<>") + countif(filter($D4:$D, $E4:$E=$J$4), "<>")
```

Each team could play on either side of the league score sheet throughout the season. So my logic is that the first 'countif' function would search through the first Team name column and Scores column to see if the team name was mentioned. If it was, it would then check to see if there was any score listed at all. If true, then it would add one to the Games played counter. The second half of the formula is to check the right side of the leagues team and score columns repeating the same process.

You can see however, that the 'GP' (games played) column lists an inaccurate amount of games played per team and even saying that teams which haven't yet played a game are at 2 games played.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra count is coming from the case when the filter returns no rows and you get #N/A. The Countif still counts it as 1.

Suggest using Countifs instead, something like

```
=countifs(B:B,J4,C:C,"<>") + countifs(E:E,J4,D:D,"<>")
```

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense! Thanks!